# $A$ is a proper subset of $B$ implies NOT($B$ subset of $A$) Proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

This is not homework. I'm just studying for my Discrete Mathematics course. I'd like to know how to prove the following using element wise proofs:

Given a *proper subset*:
$$A \subset B \iff (A \subseteq B) \land (\exists x 
\in B, \space x \notin A).$$

Prove that $(A \subset B) \rightarrow \lnot(B \subseteq A).$

I know that a proper subset $A$ is not equal but is a subset of $B$, i.e. $A=\{1,2,3\}$ and $B=\{1,2,3,4\}$ I just don't know how that proves the right hand side of the above equation.

Comment: I think it should be $$A \subset B \implies B \not\subset A$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already have that $B$ includes an element that is not in $A$.  Therefore $B$ is not a subset of $A$.

(To be a subset of $A$, every element of $B$ would have to also be an element of $A$.)

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $A \subsetneq B$. By definition of $\subsetneq$, $\exists x \in B$ such that $x \not \in A$. Therefore, $B \not \subseteq A$, or $\lnot(B\subseteq A)$.